# How do I properly return data to my client from a proxy controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, proxy

I am creating a controller with a POST method that I intend to use as a "pass-through" controller, to obtain data from a different url. The "real" url can't accept requests directly from the browser because the endpoint api requires a value that must be calculated on my server first. So within my proxy controller, I am calculating that required value and sending that value (along with the rest of the request) to the "real" url. And then my controller is getting the response from the "real" url, and passing it back down to my client (browser).

At least that's what it's supposed to do. It seems to be working mostly. However, I'm running into an issue when I pass the response back down to the browser. Here is the controller:

```
public class ProxyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index()
    {
        var paramObjects = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Request.Form.CopyTo(paramObjects);
        var parameters = paramObjects.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value.ToString()));
        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        var url = "https://the_real_url.com";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
            //CALCULATE AND ADD THE REQUIRED VALUE TO THE HEADER
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("CONNECTUSER", GetSAN());
            requestMessage.Content = encodedContent;
            var task = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ContinueWith((x) =>
            {
                response = x.Result;
            });
            task.Wait();
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And on the client, I am submitting form data to my proxy controller:

```
<form name="submitForm" id="submitForm" style="font-size: 0px;" action="@Url.Content("~/proxy")" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="MY_action" value="RUN">
    <input type="hidden" name="MY_path" value="blah/blah/blah">
    <input type="hidden" name="SN1" value="3568458">
    <input type="hidden" name="DUPLEX" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="MY_Random" value="0.5740999095141093">
    <input type="hidden" name="MY_sub_action" value="USER_ACTION">
</form>
```

As I step through the code in the controller, the response I get from my `response` object gets a 200 code back, and all the content seems to be there. But in the browser, all I see is this:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Pragma: no-cache X-XSS-protection: 0 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31557600; includeSubDomains Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 15:31:52 GMT Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=34276Y5F3425F325325H3.ajp13w; Path=/my_apps; Secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: COOKIE_HERE; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly Set-Cookie: TANOTHER_COOKIE_HERE; path=/my_apps; HTTPonly; Secure Content-Length: 11349 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT }
```

It's like I am seeing the header info within the body. In the browser, I want to see the HTML (or other type of content) that is returned from the "real" url. The content is there. I can see it when I debug. But all I am seeing in the browser is the header info. I am not sure how to properly hand that data back down to the browser. It's almost like I am returning the wrong type of object from my proxy controller or something. How can I get that data to be properly handed down to the browser?

One thing to note - the "real" url can return multiple types of data. It could be HTML, or it could be PDF, or it could be JSON. I would like my proxy controller to remain generic to handle any of those cases.

Comment: Can't repro now but I'm suspicious about `response = x.Result;`. I would try to build up a complete new response using `Request.Create...` and then transform the payload from the "real" URL into it's content. As I said - not tested.

Comment: Can't repro now but I'm suspicious about `response = x.Result;`. I would try to build up a complete new response using `Request.Create...` and then transform the payload from the "real" URL into it's content. As I said - not tested.